# Query works in Management Studio but not from client

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, visual-foxpro

Here is a query -

```
select  maclin,mamatn,caname,madesc,madtop,malstd,mastat,ISNULL(sum(tlchgv),0.00) as WIP,
    (select isnull(sum(blcost),0.00) from blfile where blclin = maclin and blmatn = mamatn) 
    as billed,
    isnull(rfhghq,0.00),isnull(rffixq,0.00),ISNULL(rfdate,'17770101'),cmidst
      from mafile,cafile,tlfile,rffile,cmfile where maclin=caclin and maclin*=tlclin 
      and mamatn*=tlmatn and
      maclin*=rfclin and mamatn*=rfmatn and maclin=cmclin and tlstat='' and
      maeact = 32 and maspca = 0
      group by maclin,mamatn,caname,madesc,madtop,malstd,mastat,rfhghq,rffixq,rfdate,cmidst
      order by caname,maclin,mamatn
```

If I run on SQL Server management Studio, the query runs in 1 second and returns 5190 rows.

When I run the exact same query from a Visual Foxpro Program on the windows XP PC desktop via ODBC, the query returns no errors but no rows!

If I add select top 5000 to the query, it works but takes 5 minutes. If I raise to select top 5200, it retunrs nothing again.

Using the same Visual Foxpro Program with SQL 2000, it works fine.

Most bizarre. Has anyone any ideas as to what may be the problem?

Comment: Why are you using old-style joins and the deprecated `*=` syntax? Have you looked to see (e.g. via Profiler) if FoxPro is somehow mangling the query before submitting it to SQL Server? Is it possible some of your tables are not in the `dbo` schema (or that the FoxPro user has a different default schema) and you're actually looking at different tables in each case? Or maybe you are connected to different versions of the database or different instances of SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, They are both looking at the same database and all the tables are there. I did try converting to left outer joins but gave up because I found it too complicated to work out the correct syntax for the query. I forgot to mention the SQL version is 2008 R2 64 bit and I have set the compatibility to 80 - SQL 2000. regards dave

Comment: It sounds like you're hitting some kind of timeout and FoxPro is giving up. Is FoxPro on the same machine as SQL Server? Are they connecting using the same login? Why do you need 80 compatibility?

Comment: Hi Aaron, SQL is on FW8 server, the PCs are on the same network. The Foxpro program returns an empty result set if I select max 5001 rows. If I select max 5000 rows, it works but takes around 3 minutes? The PC is using the same login credentials to SQL. If I don't select 80 compatibilty SQL says I need to specify correct left outer joins syntax etc. When I cut and paste the same query into sql server management studio, it returns all 5192 rows in 1 second. This has really got me baffled!

Comment: I'm not sure what an FW8 server is. It makes little sense to me that FoxPro would care how many rows you've selected unless it is timing out (which could be for a variety of reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if modern syntax still gets the results you're after without taking forever.

```
SELECT ma.maclin, ma.mamatn, ca.caname, ma.madesc, ma.madtop, ma.malstd, 
    WIP    = COALESCE(SUM(tl.tlchgv), 0.00),
    billed = COALESCE(SUM(bl.blcost), 0.00),
    rfhghq = COALESCE(rf.rfhghq, 0.00),
    rffixq = COALESCE(rf.rffizq, 0.00),
    rfdate = COALESCE(rf.rfdate, '17770101'),
    cm.cmidst
FROM dbo.mafile AS ma
INNER JOIN dbo.cafile AS ca
  ON ma.maclin = ca.caclin
INNER JOIN dbo.cmfile AS cm
  ON ma.maclin = cm.cmclin
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tlfile AS tl
  ON ma.maclin = tl.tlclin
  AND ma.mamatn = tl.tlmatn
  AND tl.tlstat = ''
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.rffile AS rf
  ON ma.mamatn = rf.rfmatn
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.blfile AS bl
  ON bl.blclin = ma.maclin 
  AND bl.blmatn = ma.mamatn
WHERE 
   ma.maeact = 32 AND ma.maspca = 0
GROUP BY 
   ma.maclin, ma.mamatn, ca.caname, ma.madesc, ma.madtop, ma.malstd,
   COALESCE(rf.rfhghq, 0.00),
   COALESCE(rf.rffizq, 0.00),
   COALESCE(rf.rfdate, '17770101'),
   cm.cmidst
ORDER BY ca.caname, ma.maclin, ma.mamatn;
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thanks for your time. I have eventually found what is causing the problem. It is a limit of Visual Foxpro of 65,000. The clue was 5,000 rows worked but 5,001 failed. 5,000 times 13 columns = 65,000.  Any more than that caused the error.  Also many thanks for the converted query. However the sum of BLFILE is missing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That limit of 65,000 applies to arrays (before VFP 9), but not to cursors. So I think something else is going on here.